# MVC3 - using template multiple times on same view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have Display and Editor templates for a model. Editor template uses jquery accordion and display template uses tabs. The problem are the IDs that have to be assigned for the jquery to work.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<SpletniObrazec.Models.Obrazec>" %>
<div id='Editor'>
  <h3><a href="#"></a>Part 1</h3>
  <div id='Editor-1'></div>
  <h3><a href="#"></a>Part 2</h3>
  <div id='Editor-2'></div>
  <h3><a href="#"></a>Part 3</h3>
  <div id='Editor-3'></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Editor').accordion();
});
</script>
```

This puts accordion to the`< div> element Editor. Now if I use this template multiple times on the same view, they will all have the same Editor ID.

I need to do this on the same view:

```
Html.EditorForModel();
Html.EditorForModel();
```

But since the template has hardcoded IDs "Editor", the second EditorForModel doesn't work with accordion.

Comment: Why are you using IDs in stead of Classes?

Comment: afaik thats how jquery operates.

Comment: You question is EXTREMELY vague.  Can you post your JS and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to put ids on each `<div>` inside the accordion, so you can drop them entirely. For the outer `<div>`, use a class instead for use in the selector enable the accordion.

```
<div class="accordion">
  <h3><a href="#"></a>Part 1</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3><a href="#"></a>Part 2</h3>
  <div></div>
  <h3><a href="#"></a>Part 3</h3>
  <div></div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordion').accordion();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but you can try put id for each object that you created. Something like next `Html.EditorForModel(new{id=SomeId});`. I see that you have answer but please check it and let me know if it works.